# PowerShell and MySQL - Leave connection open for multiple queries?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am using the MySQL connector with PowerShell and I have the need to do a query, then scrub the data a little bit and then dump the remainder to another table on the same MySQL DB.  How could I leave the connection open to make this all run a bit faster?

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
      $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
      $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
      $Connection.Open()

      $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
      $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
      $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
      $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
      return $DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Comment: you close the connection when you're done using it. there's very little point in continually opening/closing every time. that's just a waste of resources.

Comment: I know that's my point.  The above code is a function...I apologize for not making that clear.  I'm wondering how I can break it out so that I have a session I can pass around in my main PS script and then make the close call when I'm done doing the multiple tasks that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the connection object in the function that calls this function.  The called function will inherit whatever objects the calling function is maintaining, so `$Connection` will be valid in the called function.

```
function RunMe(){
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
    $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Connection.Open()

    # Call the function that executes the MySQL code
    ExecuteMySQL

    # If needed, call another function that executes the MySQL code
    ExecuteSomeOtherMySQL

    # Close the connection after all MySQL operations are complete
    $Connection.Close()
}

function ExecuteMySQL(){
    $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
    $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
    return $DataSet.Tables[0]
}
```